# Android install apk with Intent is not working in Android 10

Tags: android, file, android-intent, installation, android-10.0

I have developed application same like playstore and written below code for apk installation, which is not working in Android 10 (Android Q) device users.

```
File downloadedFile = new File(download.getFile());if (downloadedFile.exists()) {
downloadedFile.setExecutable(false);
downloadedFile.setWritable(false);
downloadedFile.setReadable(true);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(downloadedFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);}
```

Its already published and user unable to install the new version. Kindly suggest the solution for app update in users device **without front end code change.**

Comment: Please see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Comment: Please try this code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523219/4030207
I wish work for you.

Comment: This code will not work on Android 7.0+ and higher, as you will crash with a `FileUriExposedException`. Use `FileProvider`, not `Uri.fromFile()`. On Android 10+, `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` was deprecated as an action, with Google steering developers to use `PackageInstaller` instead. While they did not mention `ACTION_VIEW`, one imagines that it too is no longer appropriate for installing apps.