# When I copy file on android 31 throw IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

I need to rerecord video and copy to my Private Storage but when I copy file throw IllegalStateException

What is the solution here?

[This video shows how the crash occurs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yvgV6nd5-IuzafKHQdA5mrYclz-Pt-uw/view?usp=sharing)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-25-thread-1
Process: com.majd.paraibachat, PID: 13789
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only owner is able to interact with pending item content://media/external_primary/video/media/150
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2433)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:153)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:780)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:2027)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1842)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1518)
    at com.majd.paraibachat.persistance.FileBackend.copyFileToPrivateStorage(FileBackend.java:716)
    at com.majd.paraibachat.persistance.FileBackend.copyFileToPrivateStorage(FileBackend.java:917)
    at com.majd.paraibachat.services.AttachFileToConversationRunnable.processAsFile(AttachFileToConversationRunnable.java:71)
    at com.majd.paraibachat.services.AttachFileToConversationRunnable.run(AttachFileToConversationRunnable.java:176)
    at com.majd.paraibachat.utils.SerialSingleThreadExecutor$Runner.run(SerialSingleThreadExecutor.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: Who is the file's owner?

Comment: Try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66812986/6037561](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66812986/6037561) hope this will help you

Comment: The content has not completed downloading yet. You need to provide a [mcve] showing not only your `copyFileToPrivateStorage()` method but also where you are getting this `Uri` from.

Comment: I added a video of how the crash occurred

Comment: Post your related code.